# Перевести числа, разделенные пробелами из строки в массив целых чисел

Tags: c, массивы, строки, ввод

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char s[100+1];
    int i;
    int num[20];
    fgets(s, 20, stdin);
    for(i=0;i<20;i++) {
        num[i]= atoi(s);
    }
    puts(s);
    printf("%d",num[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Я пытался что-то сделать, но я не понимаю как использовать atoi для обработки всех символов строки, а не только символов до пробела.

Comment: А почему не просто `scanf` в элементы массива? почему именно из строки?

Comment: По условиям задачи нужно из строки достать все числа и занести их в массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если нужна именно строка, я бы делал [примерно так](https://ideone.com/ZsQoPe):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char s[100+1],*e,*b = s;
    int d,i = 0;
    int num[20];
    fgets(s, 101, stdin);

    for(d = strtol(b,&e,10); e != b && errno == 0;d = strtol(b = e,&e,10))
    {
        num[i++]= d;
    }
    puts(s);
    for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        printf("%d  ",num[j]);
}
```